# Как построить обмен между серверной частью на java и клиентами на android?

Tags: java, spring, клиент-сервер

Сервер принимает запрос (скажем до 100) одновременно и либо отсылает изображение / список изображений клиенту (андроид), либо генерирует его и просит обратиться позже.

Хотелось бы написать серверную часть на java/spring. Пока сделал все ручками через сокеты - работает. Что у спринга может помочь построить такой сервер? То есть какой стек технологий лучше использовать? Продолжать обмениваться просто через сокеты и строить свои пакеты или это изобретение велосипеда, который уже написан?

Спасибо.

Comment: Выбор технологии - это ваша работа, так как только вы знаете все требования и вы берете на себя ответственность за результат. Но если что то и советовать, то я бы выбрал HTTP сервер вместо игр с сокетами хотя бы потому, что его легче тестировать, проще писать клиентов, и уже полно HTTP серверов из коробки.

Comment: Т.е. Spring MVC(если юзаете спринг бут - веб стартер). Он предоставляет множество аннотаций для построения REST API

Comment: @tym32167 То есть построить гибридное приложение на андроид, где клиенты будут работать с HTML. Не подходит - мне просто не нравится HTML. Несколько отдает халтурой, хотя это субъективно.

Comment: @AntonSorokin Спасибо, покопаю.

Comment: Не путайте http и html. Вы можете построить сервер, который отдает json или xml.